# invoice2data - Ignoring *Item line* because it doesn't match anything

Tags: regex, invoice

I'm using invoice2data to extract fields from an invoice. However it seems that the invoice items could not be matched I don't know why. Here's how my invoice looks:

[image]

And here's my code:

```
lines:
  start: Valoarea TVA
  end: Data scadenta
  line: (?P<crt>\d+)[ ]*(?P<name>(?:(?:[a-z0-9A-Z\-\/])+[ ]{1})+)(?:[ ]*)(?P<um>[a-z]*)(?:[ ]*)(?P<quantity>\d+)(?:[ ]*)(?P<price>\d+)(?:[ ]*)(?P<value>\d+)(?:[ ]*)(?P<vat_value>\d+)
```

Could someone point me in the right direction as to why I get the following messages logged?

```
ignoring * 1                Prestari servicii curierat Locker NextDay            val        1                83.79                              83.79                  15.92* because it doesn't match anything
ignoring * 2                Prestari servicii curierat 24H                       val        1                86.5    

                       86.5                   16.44* because it doesn't match anything
```

Comment: Can you post text instead of an image? What do you mean by the asterix in the "logged messages" parts like `ignoring * 1` Did you add those yourself? Also can you update the question with the expected matches?

Comment: `ignoring * 1 ...` is what I get when I run the invoice2data script on my invoice pdf. I want to match the list of products in my invoice (first photo attached) but I currently get no matches `'lines': [],`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get invoice products by using this regex:

`line: (?P<crt>\d+)\s+(?P<name>(?:(?:[a-z0-9A-Z\-\/])+[ ]{1})+)\s+(?P<um>[a-z]*)(?:[ ]*)\s+(?P<quantity>\d+)(?:[ ]*)\s+(?P<price>\d+.\d+)\s+(?P<value>\d+.\d+)\s+(?P<vat_value>\d+.\d+)`